# javascript hide div 1 if div 2 is visible?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to create a piece of javascript, i am wanting to create a function that says if one div is visible prevent another one from opening or if div 1 is visible hide div 2 on page load.

Can someone show me how i can do this. Thanks.

```
<script>

      window.onload (function () {
        if  ($('.welcome_overlay').is(":visible")) {
            $("#cover").hide();


                    }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what's the issue? what does `$('#cover')` give you when you run it in a console? when you log it from within the onload? have you included jquery? we need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onload` syntax is incorrect - you're trying to call it with syntax similar to jQuery methods but that's not how it works. Rather than trying to *call* `onload` and pass it a function as a parameter you need to *assign* it equal to a function:

```
window.onload = function () {
    if  ($('.welcome_overlay').is(":visible")) {
        $("#cover").hide();
    }
};
```

Or since you seem to be using jQuery why not use a jQuery ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if  ($('.welcome_overlay').is(":visible")) {
        $("#cover").hide();
    }
});
```

Either way your code won't work unless you include the jQuery script before your script.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id='Div1'></div><div id='Div2'></div>
```

Javascript:

```
if(document.getElementById("Div1").style.visibility == "visible") {
    document.getElementById("Div2").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```